# Exclude files from a list using Robocopy within PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an automated `robocopy`, but due to auto sorting the files move around a bit. So I have a script that now grabs all the filenames from the folders and compiles a text file with the list of filenames using

```
Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse -Name | Out-File $textfile
```

Then I run `robocopy` but would like it to check the list of files already in the directory using the text file.

```
robocopy $server $Folder *.* /minage:$date /maxage:$date /XF:$textfile
```

all these PowerShell files are run one after the other like so

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\BuildList.ps1
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\CopyFiles.ps1
```

Comment: /XF ignore files matching the given pattern, not reading from a file. robocopy by default ignore already existing files in destination, you dont need to provide a list unless you surely want to.

Comment: thanks but my hierarchy is as like this C:\Folder\Folder1, C:\Folder\Folder2, then i robocopy \\Server to C:\Folder then i auto SORT into Folder1 and Folder2. Robocopy wont look in the subdirectories to check if files already exist.

Comment: Add switch /COPYALL and /MIR, this 2 switch will mirror the folder from source to destination, be careful and test first, robocopy can remove files in destination. A typical use to mirror a folder is "robocopy.exe \\server\folder \\server2\folder * /copyall /mir"

Comment: thanks, good tip. not what i need though unfortunately, i want to pull the files across and the sort them into other folders. this would delete what ive sorted and double handle. mirrored copy is not what i need. thanks

Comment: I believe robocopy can't do what you want. You'll need to write your own script to check files.

Comment: What do you mean you "auto sort into folder1 and folder2"? Sort what? How? Currently it's completely unclear to me what you want to accomplish or what isn't working. Please show sample input as well as the desired and actual output you're getting.

Comment: I assume they are copying files from remote server to C:\Folder. Then the files are (somehow) sorted/moved from C:\Folder into subfolders (C:\Folder\Folder1 & C:\Folder\Folder2). On next copy from remote server, David wants robocopy to check if the files are already in one of the subfolders and not copy them from the remote server if so. As has been said this isn't possible with robocopy.

Comment: It might be doable with a combination of PowerShell and `robocopy`, but with that little information it's impossible to tell.

Comment: thanks everyone, it seems there are limitations to easily do this, my best option is a more detailed script that uses xcopy.